# Scroll Linear Layout Android Studio

Tags: java, android

Tengo una lista de videos en un LinearLayout pero no hace scroll y si lo pongo dentro de un ScrollView Yya no me muestra la lista de videos,aqui esta dentro de un ScrollView:

Codigo XML:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Codigo Java:

```
package com.example.aplicacionestados;
```

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.VideoView;
import static android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class videos_activity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
public VideoView video;
public ImageView imagen;
public Button button;
Bitmap bitmap;


public String obtener_extension(String file)
{
    Integer tamaño=file.length();
    return file.substring(tamaño-3,tamaño);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_videos_activity);













    LinearLayout lista_videos = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_byron);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT );









    File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    String path = dir.getAbsolutePath() + "/DCIM";// + "/WhatsApp/Media/.Statuses";



    File carpeta = new File(path);
    String[] listado = carpeta.list();

    if (listado == null || listado.length == 0)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No hay elementos dentro de la carpeta actual", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
    else {


        for (int i=0; i<listado.length; i++) {
```

if(obtener_extension(listado[i]).equalsIgnoreCase("mp4"))
{

```
            video = new VideoView(this);
            video.setLayoutParams(lp);
            video.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path + "/" + listado[i]));
            video.seekTo( 1 );
            video.stopPlayback();;
            lista_videos.addView(video);
```

}

```
        }
    }






}
```

}

Sin agregar el ScrollView me muestra lños videos pero no hace scroll:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Estoy casi seguro que el error esta el archivo de diseño, podrias publicar el codigo de archivo XML donde implementas el scrollView?

Comment: Snchz Eder en la foto esta el xml  cuando uso SCROLLVIEW los videos no aparece, se queda vacio igual

Comment: Creo que lo que necesitas es implementar un ListView o RecyclerView, porque quieres mostrar una lista y hacer scroll down-up.  El approach de usar ScrollView y un contenedor LinearLayout en el que vas añadiendo listas no es correcto.

Comment: @Javier la propiedad "layout_height" del LinearLayout ponlo en "wrap_parent", opcionalmente tambien puedes aliminar los tres primero atributos y el ultimo atributo que le pones a tu linear layout (es codigo no importante en el lugar donde estan)

Answer (score 0):

Lo correcto sería que usaras un elemento List View o mejor un Recycler View. Si no los conoces estos te permiten agregar items de un mismo tipo a traves de un adaptador. Si quieres puedes guiarte por alguna de estas respuestas:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40584424/simple-android-recyclerview-example